# Opencart CDN's suggestions

Tags: opencart, cdn, cloudflare, opencart2.x

I have been using OpenCart for our site, I am really happy with it, it is an awesome platform that comes with many features and a big community around it. Can someone guide which CDN should is use? What are the important things in the website for which i have to use CDN services. I haven't managed to find any module for this. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't give us full information on what you want to accomplish.  Also, **there actually are some modules**, that make CDN integration.
Also, most CDN services **don't** require a special plugin, bit can do their magic on the fly, for example like CloudFlare, and their setup is rather basic.

Here is a list of free modules: 
https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension&filter_license=0&filter_search=cdn

For example, if you would like to have an ImageCDN - KeyCDN has this service and the module utilizes it. Juts an example.

Cloudflare has a good free account service and even better Pro (2nd level) plan, that is good enough for any starter shop. Paid plan has these extras:

- Enhanced security with Web Application Firewall (WAF)
- Enhanced performance with image and mobile optimization - lossless compression for images and WebP format
- HTTP/2 prioritization